# Inverse rotation of Axis/Angle

Tags: matrices

I have 3d objects which are translated at certain z from each other and rotated. The information of the rotations are saved in the vector as AxisAngle format: {x_vec, y_vec, z_vec, teta_angle}. So I have a certain chain and I want to reverse it, meaning that he last unit should be first, etc. So all the rotations must be changed accordingly, i.e. reversed/inversed. Unfortunately I can't find a proper way to do that, could someone advise? It's not just an opposite angle, the vectors itself must be transformed accordingly.